# Visualize 2d objects in 2d image in rviz

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to visualize some 2d objects using lines or bounding boxes in a 2d image in RVIZ. So far I was not able to find a way. I am suspecting that this might not be supported by RVIZ. But since I only started using ROS it is also likely that I was just looking at the wrong place.

Here is what I found out so far:

- I can visualize things in 3D using markers.
- I can visualize an image using the display type Image.
- I can also visualize an image using the display type camera, and I think if there is correct calibration information, the 3d markers get projected in that image.

But is there a way to directly draw something like the markers into a 2d image?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298685/visualize-2d-objects-in-2d-image-in-rviz/) by [sietschie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36663/sietschie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way to do this is to make your own node which [subscribes](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/SubscribingToImages) to the image topic, draws the markers on top of the image and [publishes](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages) it on a new topic. I do this for debugging vision algorithms on a regular basis.

The image transport package can be used to receive and publish openCV images, openCV's basic drawing functions are described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html).

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LMerCy](https://answers.ros.org/users/89356/lmercy/) on 2021-11-11**:
I really need this..The way draw by a node cannot solve if i have multiple boxes from different node, which will publish too much new images..Is there any way to solve as rviz plugin?